# Get All User Roles in DNN

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, roles

```
public DnnRole GetDnnRoleByName(int portalId, string dnnRoleName)
        {
            DnnRole role = null;
            try
            {                
                RoleController rc = new RoleController();
                RoleInfo dnnRole = rc.GetRoleByName(portalId, dnnRoleName);

                if (dnnRole != null)
                {
                    role = new DnnRole();
                    role.Id = dnnRole.RoleID;
                    role.RoleName = dnnRole.RoleName;
                    role.Description = dnnRole.Description;

                }
            }
```

Above is my code to get the Roles for many purposes and this DNN predefined method. But when I try to get the Role ID for **All Users**(DNN default role) it gives a error. Because this role does not has portal Id. Can you please advice is there any way to get this with out hard code the role id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go...

```
RoleController RoleController = new RoleController();
IList<RoleInfo> roleInfoArr = RoleController.GetRoles(PortalId);

foreach (RoleInfo roleInfo in roleInfoArr)
{
    if (roleInfo.RoleName == "All Users")
    {
        Response.Write(roleInfo.RoleID);
    }
}
```

But the ID for `All Users` is always `-1` for every Portal.

For `Superusers` it's `-2`

For `Unauthenticated Users` it's `-3`

Note that the `Administrator` roleId IS different per portal

Comment: can you please advice that if I have more than 2 portals within the same DNN instance. Then this All user role will be common for both portals or not? that is the main concern for me to use portal Id.

Comment: Yes, the ID is always -1 for every portal. See the table `Roles` in the DNN database.